# Import Schema on pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, json, apache-spark, pyspark

I am new to python. I am trying to read a JSON file that contains my schema definition. It looks like :

```
{
  "type" : "struct",
  "fields" : [ {
    "name" : "name",
    "type" : "string",
    "nullable" : true,
    "metadata" : { }
  }, {
    "name" : "address",
    "type" : "string",
    "nullable" : true,
    "metadata" : { }
  }, {
    "name" : "comment",
    "type" : "string",
    "nullable" : true,
    "metadata" : { }
  }
}
```

I have a data set, and on that i need to apply above json schema, I have tried below code :

`targetDf = spark.createDataFrame(inputDf.rdd, schemaFieldsOne)`

However, here I need to specify the 'schemaFieldsOne' a struct type, I want to read the JSON and convert it into Python struct type so that I can apply that StructType to my data frame(.to add).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```py
import pyspark.sql.types as T
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

with open('./schema.txt', 'r') as S:  # path to your schema file
    saved_schema = json.load(S)

schema = T.StructType.fromJson(json.loads(saved_schema))

df = spark.createDataFrame(yourRdd, schema)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, when i run that i an getting :
`TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not 'dict'` .
Looks like the json.loads expecting a some specific format.

Comment: After trying many things with dumps and dump and load and load , below is the code that worked :
`with open('inout.json', 'r') as S:  # path to your schema file
    saved_schema = json.load(S)
targetDf = spark.createDataFrame(inputDf.rdd, StructType.fromJson(saved_schema))`